# ArgMin Returning Indeterminate Values (Steepest Descent w/ Exact Line Search)

Tags: mathematical-optimization

To learn Mathematica, I'm attempting to implement a basic steepest descent algorithm (i.e., Cauchy's gradient descent).

In an effort to improve upon previous code, I'm trying to implement an exact line search with the ArgMin function, as seen below. (Note: I removed the iterative functionality while troubleshooting this issue).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define function to be evaluated*) 
f[x_, y_] := 
  2*((x - 1)^2)*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] + ((x + 1)^2)*
    Exp[-2*((x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2)];

(*Generate random starting point on x-y plane*)
{x0, y0} = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2];

(*Define dx, dy for Central Differences*)
dx = 10*^-5;   dy = 10*^-5;

(*Compute components of gradient w/ central differences*)
dfdx = (f[(x0 + dx), y0] - f[(x0 - dx), y0])/(2*dx);
dfdy = (f[x0, (y0 + dy)] - f[x0, (y0 - dy)])/(2*dy);

(* Define functions for ArgMin wrt α *) 
gx[α_] := f[x0, y0] - α*dfdx;
gy[α_] := f[x0, y0] - α*dfdy;

(* Attempt ArgMin implementation *) 
αx = ArgMin[gx[α], α]
αy = ArgMin[gy[α], α]
```

When ArgMin is called, it is returning an Indeterminate value, along with the warning "NMaximize: The problem is unbounded". From my understanding, the gx and gy functions that I have defined are essentially straight lines and thus unbounded by nature. When I attempted to apply bounds (-10 <= alpha <= 10) ArgMin returns either -10 or 10, which seems strange to me.

My main question is this: Is there a way to implement Argmin to enable a workable exact line search, or would a different approach to line search be more effective for this problem?

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: Erm. For the line search, you should minimize `f` and not its linearization. So try this: `ArgMin[f[x0 + α dfdx, y0 +α dfdy], α]`.

Comment: Notice that `ArgMin` will use inexact numerica methods to find a minimum. So this is not really exact line search. Fortunately, exact line search is not really needed (and sometimes even to helpful). Moreover, notive that your picked example function `f` is a bit hard to minimize due to the expontentials.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information @Hen

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher if it's not too much of a hassle, I've run into some more confusion. If I wanted to implement gradient _ascent_ instead of _descent_, would the following modification to the calculation of ArgMin be valid?                            
 [Alpha] = 
  ArgMin[f[(x0 + \[Alpha]*dfdx), (y0 + \[Alpha]*dfdy)], \[Alpha]];

Comment: Nope. You want to have `ArgMax[{f[x0 + α dfdx, y0 +α dfdy], α>0}, α]`: We walk in direction of gradient, and then maximize. Btw. for _descent_, we want to go in _downward_ direction. So it should be `ArgMin[{f[x0 - α dfdx, y0 - α dfdy], α>0}, α]`. Sorry, that was my fault.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks for this additional information! I have a better grasp on this concept now.